# google maps api v3 - javascript - perspective / tilt (not satellite!) ?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know it's possible in Flash:
http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/Map3DSimple.html

The perspective control.. any one knows when or if it'll be available in the JS api?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  There is no such control currently in the Google Maps JavaScript API V3.